# Sinch SDK and detect facial IOS

Tags: ios, face-recognition, sinch

I'm beginning to integrate Sinch SDK in my project IOS but I want to know if it's possible to add a detection facial in the same classe

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Its not, we dont provide access to the video stream during a call

Comment: Can you integrate facial detection for SDK IOS and like that you will have an added value compared to TWILIO

Comment: It will be better if you give access to stream buffer or `SINAVcaptureSession` so we can add custom functionality